# Populating a dojo combobox when dojo.ready (dojo 1.7)

Tags: dom, combobox, dojo

I have a comboxbox loading its data from a url store. My code is below... What I noticed in Firebug is that the Combobox loads this info once I put the focus on it. I would love to have the Combobox to populate when the page is done loading.I am guessing I use dojo.ready for this? Does anyone have a suggestion as to how I would pull this off? Many thanks! Janie

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />
    <style type="text/css">html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }</style>
    <script src="lib/dojo/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad: true"></script>
    <script>require(["dojo/ready", "dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore", "dijit/form/ComboBox"]); 

</script>

</head>
<body class="claro">
    <label for="user">User: </label>
<div dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore" url="test.json" jsId="countryStore"> 
<input dojoType="dijit.form.ComboBox" searchAttr="last_name" store="countryStore" class="selectionNav tableData" value="" name="last_name" id="test.json" /> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

your require function should look something like this

```
require(["dojo/ready", "dijit/registry", "dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore"],function(dom,reg,store){
    var combo = dijit.byId("test.json");
    var storeDate = new store({url:"path/to/file.json"});
    try{
        combo.store(storeData);
    }catch(e){
        combo.set("store",storeData)
    }
});
```

the try catch statement is because I don't remember which is the correct one